# Gradle project refresh failed using offline SDK in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I installed latest version of android studio. I already have downloaded SDK. I placed it inside  `C:\Users\-----\AppData\Local\Android` But when i tried to build my app (was working fine with older version of android studio) , it gives the error

> Error:Cause: startup failed:
>   initialization script 'C:\Users-------\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit5.gradle': 17: unable to resolve class org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder
>    @ line 17, column 1.
>      import org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.internal.ExtraModelBuilder
>      ^
>
> 1 error

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38712509/gradle-appname-project-refresh-failed) and applied the solution of `offline mode` but still did not work.
When I buid the project it shows ;
[image]

and in console;

[image]

In offline pannel, it gives error of gradle location;

[image]

Comment: Can you post `ijini5.gradle`?

Comment: @azizbekian Where it will be?

Comment: As seen in error message `C:\Users-------\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit5.gradle`.

Comment: @azizbekian there is not `ijinit5.gradle` but a file with name `ijinit.gradle`